# How to use R packages in Power BI?

Tags: r, powerbi

I have plotted the graph using a code in R using library function which is part of certain package.

I want to use this code in powerbi to plot the graph. But I am not able to add the package (library function) in power bi?

Comment: You can add a R script in powerbi i.e. click on Get Data and then click on the R script and paste the code

Answer (score 2):

For a Power BI Desktop scenario, it calls the R Installation specified in the Power BI Options.  So you need to add the packages you want via that R Installation.

For an app.powerbi.com scenario, you are limited to the list of packages they support, ref:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-r-visuals/

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, are you trying to install packages or add packages that you already have into R?

Unfortunately Power BI isn't an IDE for the R language, so you will need to install the packages that you want via your R IDE or command prompt.

If you are trying to use packages that are already installed on your machine, for example, the package `plotrix`, then you can use the R script editor in the Visualisations tab like this:

```
require(plotrix)
```

or

```
library(plotrix)
```

Please post an update to show if this has helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Was just now gone through the same problem: everything was loading fine except the visual created with R which required me to use [ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) and it was giving an error saying

> there is no package called ggplot2

In order to solve it, opened RStudio and in the console ran

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

[image: Install ggplot2]

Then, went back to PowerBI and clicked "Atualizar" (which means "Update" in portuguese)

[image: PowerBI portuguese language update]

and the visual showed up without any errors.