# how to load R packages in Power BI

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

Power BI has a built-in R editor which you can use to create R visuals for your Power BI dashboards. Unfortunately, it can't seem to locate my loaded ggplot2 package when I run the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=label, y=value)) +geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

> R script error. Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package
>   called 'ggplot2'

The ggplot2 is already installed and loaded in my R environment. In addition, my R home directory is set in Power BI and I've already created basic R plots that do not require additional packages to confirm that is working fine. In the R script editor, I've also tried replacing `library(ggplot2)` with `library("ggplot2", lib.loc="C:/path-to-my-r-packages")` but no success so far. Any tips you have would be greatly appreciated! This question has also been posted on the [Power BI community forum](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-load-R-packages/m-p/201638).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461473/how-to-use-r-packages-in-power-bi

Comment: https://powerbi.tips/2016/09/digging-deeper-with-r-visuals-for-powerbi/

Comment: The existing answers don't provide a solution to this problem